# Fixed PanelGrid in JSF while scrolling (primefaces)

Tags: css, jsf, panelgrid

I need to set the panelGrid fixed while scrolling the page.

e.g. the bottom bar on the top should be fixed, while scrolling the datatable.

```
    <h:panelGrid id="buttonGrid">
....
</h:panelGrid>


<p:dataTable id="datatable" .....>
....
</p:dataTable>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
<h:panelGrid id="buttonGrid" styleClass="fixed-class">
            <h:outputText value="text text"/>
            <h:outputText value="text text"/>
            <h:outputText value="text text"/>
            <h:outputText value="text text"/>
            <h:outputText value="text text"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

css:

```
.fixed-class{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Your response give me an idea about my solution. My CSS has the `position: fixed;`